# How to create logout with springboot security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

Here is my login. I would implement a logout method with `path("/logout")` so that the current user-session go really logout. I am using Spring Security

```
@POST
@Path("/login")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response login(User credentials) {

    if(credentials == null){
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
    }

    try {
        User userInfo = new User();
        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(credentials.getUsername

        // Create authRequest Object with User ind DB, Credentials from Web-client
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, credentials.getPassword(), userDetails.getAuthorities());

        // Authenticate the user
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(authRequest);
        SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);

        userInfo.setUsername(authentication.getName());

        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity("Login succesfull").build();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
        return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).entity("Login failed").build();
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what is your question ?

Comment: @Ravi How can I code a logout ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@GetMapping("/logout")
    public String getLogoutPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication != null)
            new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, authentication);

        return "redirect:/login";
    }
```

Comment: Basically it invalidates the session and clears authentication from the security context.

Answer (score 1):

Without WebSecuirtyConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final CustomAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf().disable()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .and()
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use spring security adapter.

check the docs : https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-logout

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {



    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http               
                .logout().logoutUrl("/logout.html");

    }
}
```